# How to escape a parenthesis in a perl pie one-liner?

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I want to replace all occurrences of "foo" with "bar(" in all files that contain "foo". I have tried

```
perl -pie 's/foo/bar\(/g' `grep -ril foo .`
```

but that just hangs and nothing happens. I have tried varying the number of escape backslashes in front of the opening parenthesis, but to no success. I'm working in bash 4.1.5.

The replacement works fine if I remove the opening parenthesis. Does anyone know how to escape the opening parenthesis?

Comment: Interesting. Running your command with `-MO=Deparse` indicates that your bracket escape isn't getting passed through. Double escaping doesn't help though, because then it _does_.

Comment: You should be getting an error like `Can't open perl script "s/foo/bar\(/g": No such file or directory`, since anything immediately following `-i` is used as the extension for the backup file (in this case, just `e`). `perl -i -pe 's/foo/bar(/g` should work fine, no need to escape parentheses in the replacement.

Comment: You don't have to escape a `special regex character` in a replacement string since it is only a string.

Comment: This has nothing with your problem, only nitpicking: in `bash` is better to write `$(grep -ril ...)` e.g. using `$()` construction, instead of the backticks. It is more readable and also nestable.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: that's an answer, I think, not a comment

Comment: @ysth The OP said their shell just hangs, so I'm assuming they ran a different command than they're showing us. Maybe they forgot a closing quote or backtick, like I did in my previous comment. I'll make it an answer if they come back and clarify.

Answer (score 7):

What you posted exits immediately as Perl tries to open `s/foo/bar\(/g` as a source file since the `e` is treated the argument of `-i`.

```
$ perl -pie 's/foo/bar\(/g' `grep -ril foo .`
Can't open perl script "s/foo/bar\(/g": No such file or directory
```

I'm guessing you ran the following instead:

```
perl -i -pe's/foo/bar\(/g' `grep -ril foo .`
```

This will hang when `grep` finds nothing. When no arguments are given, the `-i` is effectively ignored. The program will read from STDIN and write to STDOUT. So, when `grep` returns nothing, this program will block waiting for input from STDIN.

Solution:

```
grep -ril foo . | xargs perl -i -pe's/foo/bar\(/ig'
```